# Compute $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2}\sin(s^2)ds\right) $

Tags: calculus

Is it correct to do the following?
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2}\sin(s^2)ds\right) = F(b)-F(a)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x^4)2x^2-\cos(0)(0))$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x^4)2x^2)$$
$$-8x^5\sin(x^4)+4x\cos(x^4).$$

Comment: Don't use double dollar signs in the title, it messes up the spacing on the main page.

Comment: Yes it is. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html

Comment: Apparently, you tried to evaluate the integral first. But you did not obtain the correct antiderivative. The method is sound, but your execution is flawed. So, no... There are quicker ways to proceed, using the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), as in the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

Introduce

$$ f \, : \, x \, \mapsto \, \int_{0}^{x} \sin(s^{2}) \: ds $$

and

$$ g \, : \, x \, \mapsto \, x^{2} $$

Then, $\int_{0}^{x^{2}} \sin(s^{2}) \: ds = f(g(x))$. Knowing that :

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} f(x) = \sin(x^{2}) $$

and

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} g(x) = 2x $$

Using the chain rule, you have :

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) \times g'(x) $$

which gives :

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} f(g(x)) = 2x\sin(x^{4}) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt = f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x). $$

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$F(x)=\int_0^{x}\sin(s^2)ds$$
and $u(x)=x^2$ and you want to differentiate $F\circ u$ so  the chain rule gives

$$(F\circ u)'(x)=u'(x)\times F'(u(x)) =2x\sin(x^4)$$